# An **atom** is the smallest constituent unit of ordinary matter that has the properties of a chemical element

Tags: atoms

An **atom** is the smallest constituent unit of ordinary matter that has the properties of a chemical element.

**my Question**:ordinary matter = chemical element???

A **chemical compound** is an entity consisting of two or more atoms, at least two from different elements, which associate via chemical bonds .

**my Question**: Is a single molecule can be a compound? ??

A **chemical element**  is a species of atoms having the same number of protons in their atomic nuclei .

**my Question**: Is a single atom can be a compound ???

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, in simplest terms, ordinary matter is the elements. It's what we see and interact with everyday, although it only makes up 4% of the universe.
2. In many cases, a molecule can be a compound, as long as it includes two *different* atoms. Something like H2 is a molecule but not a compound because it only has one unique element.
3. No, a compound must have *two* different atoms.

Hope that helps!